# Change variables via command line NSIS installer

Tags: command-line, installation, command-line-arguments, nsis

I would like to change variables within NSIS through command line arguments. I see in the documentation you can change global variables, but not created ones within the NSIS script.

For example: if I had

```
Var example
StrCpy $example "C:\Program Files (x86)\Installer"
```

Is it possible to change the example variable string through command line arguments?

Answer (score 4):

```
OutFile "MySetup.exe"
Name "MySetup"
RequestExecutionLevel user

!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Var MyVar

Function .onInit
StrCpy $MyVar "Default value"

${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $0 "/MyVar=" $1 ; Get suffix after "/MyVar=" switch
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    StrCpy $MyVar $1
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
MessageBox mb_OK MyVar:$MyVar
SectionEnd
```

and execute as `"MySetup.exe" /MyVar="Hello world"`